# Cursor flicker in TextInput react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Known issue with input flickering when using a mask.

I tried to solve it using two inputs, one for output and one for input. But I still have only the carriage flicker. How will solve this problem?

My code

```
            const Wrapper = React.memo(() => {
                const [value, setValue] = useState('')
                return (
                    <View style={styles.root}>
                        <MaskInput
                            mask={BIK}
                            value={value}
                            style={[styles.commonInput, styles.inputReadonly]}
                            placeholder={'0000000'}
                            selectionColor={'black'}
                            caretHidden={true}
                        />
            
                        <MaskInput
                            mask={BIK}
                            value={value}
                            onChangeText={onInput}
                            style={[styles.commonInput, styles.input]}
                            placeholder={'0000000'}
                            selectionColor={'black'}
                        />
                    </View>
                )
            })
```